# how to print a date string with timezone

Tags: php

How to print/get a date string like this in PHP? Are there some build-in functions to print ISO date strings?

```
Thu, 19 Jan 2017 17:01:27 +0100
```

Comment: Did you look at the PHP date function .. ? everything is explained in doc.

Comment: Yes, but there must be some standard methods to do this.. This textual date string is from a email header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at date function documentation. This is enough :

```
$date = date("D, d M Y G:i:s O");
```

Or to format specific MYSQL date (for example) :

```
$date = date("D, d M Y G:i:s O", strtotime($yourDate));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: The OP specifically replied to a comment that the date function was not sufficient for their needs. They wanted a pre-built format.

Comment: You are kind of people wasting their time to find a library when 1 row of code is enought to answer their problem ? I am not. It works, and you won't find any shorter way.

Comment: If there is a method to generate a standard ISO datestamp thats to prefer.. But your solution works.. I was just looking for a method to print standard ISO datestamps so you dont have to write them yourself

Comment: Define the format as a contant in your code. Then use the constant. Here is your method. Your format is not an ISO standard (look at formats here : http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). So when you can use a 1-row function, use it.

Comment: @VincentDecaux He was asking for a library, so I gave it to him. If I had to do it my way, I would have chosen your solution.

Comment: @AdamEdison-MusicEducator Datetime is just the OOP version of date function. This is not a library, and it requires PHP 7.

Comment: @VincentDecaux, tried to edit your answer so I can upvote it again.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does, indeed. One of the few nice benefits of working with PHP. Haha.
http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

```
const string ISO8601 = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sO" ;
const string ATOM = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP" ;
```

These are already defined in the DateTime class.
You could obviously supply your own format string to suite your needs.

```
public static DateTime DateTime::createFromFormat ( string $format , string $time [, DateTimeZone $timezone ] )
```

Read more here as well:

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php